# json_encode returns null for a non-null value

Tags: php, json

What's wrong with this code?

```
$a = Array (
    "password" => "SeRjQRVUglkeM‰‰P9L7NsjKXOY", //it's encrypted with a custom encryption system
    "id" => 0
);
echo json_encode($a);
```

What am I getting:

```
{"password":null,"id":0}
```

What is the output i want:

```
{"password":"SeRjQRVUglkeM‰‰P9L7NsjKXOY","id":0}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use your 'own' encryption engine and not the standard sha1() or with a random hash? I think that's more secure than brewing your own encryption thingy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`json_encode` expects valid UTF-8 and will not encode values which are not valid UTF-8. If your "custom encrypted values" contain binary data, as I assume, it's not safe for transport via JSON. You should [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/base64_encode) the value, so it uses transportable ASCII characters only.